# Apollo client not calling with correct variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-testing-library

I have a query like

```
export default gql`
    query getStatus($statusInput: StatusInput!) {
        getStatus(statusInput: $statusInput) {
            canAccess
            isCorrect
        }
    }
`;
```

And then I have a hook that uses this query

```
const useStatus = () => {
    const [someId] = useId();
    return useQuery<{ getStatus: StatusResponse }>(getStatus, {
        variables: { statusInput: { id: someId, numValue: 1 } },
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        skip: !cartId,
        ssr: false,
    });
};
```

And I am using it in my component as

```
const { data: statusData, loading: dataLoading, variables } = useStatus();
```

In the the component.spec.tsx I have

```
const mocks = [
    {
        request: {
            query: getStatus,
            variables: {
                statusInput: {
                    id: '1234',
                    numValue: 55,
                },
            },
        },
        result: {
            data: {
                getStatus: {
                    __type: 'StatusResponse',
                    canAccess: true,
                    isCorrect: true
                },
            }
        },
    },
];
```

and inside the test I have

```
    const { queryByTestId, container } = renderWithProviders(
        <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={true} cache={inMemoryCache}>
            <Component />
        </MockedProvider>,
        { mockedContextData: someContextMocks }
    );
```

But when I print `variables` in the component, I get

```
{ checkoutStatusInput: { id: '', numValue: 1 } }
```

instead of the values I passed in the mocks.

Did I miss something?

Comment: mocking request doesn't mean mocking component [props/state]

Comment: @xadm, no, but shouldnt shouldnt those variables at least be called with the mocked variables I set?

Comment: not, it shouldn't ... it's for useQuery hook internal usage ... you should also pass a `cartId` explicitely [for `useStatus` context/testing]

Comment: @xadm so can you please tell me how I can fake that hook response to test this component ?